# C# Visual studio Issues with install and after

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Recently i have decided to learn c# using the IDE VB platform. I downloaded the open sourced software on the Microsoft website however i have had constant problems since none of which i received with any Java alternative.

I have downloaded and uninstalled it twice, the first time i try to run any form of class even a blank program. I will get a warning stating a Trojan Horse is present (Luckily my AVG managed to get it).

Then when ever i try to run the file, i will get the error code CS2012, and nothing happens.

I am wondering does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it or potentially know of any other free software for c#.

I have included the code which I am using below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("basic input output");
        GetUserData();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void GetUserData()
    {
        Console.Write("please enter your name: ");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("please enter your age: ");
        string userAge = Console.ReadLine();

        //changes echo colour
        ConsoleColor prevColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.red;

        //echo to console
        Console.WriteLine("hello {0}! Your are {1} years old.", userName, userAge);

        //Restore previous color
        Console.ForegroundColor = prevColor;
    }   
}
```

Thanks Joe

Comment: I can guarantee the official download from the Microsoft page does not have a virus. This code is also fine and would run under normal circumstances. It sounds like you have issues with your PC which is something we can't assist with.

Comment: Yeah i am aware it is unusual hence why i posted it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a common issue:

I guess your virus scanner detects YOUR program as suspicious and prevents the execution (or kills it right away). I have the same problem with Avast AntiVirus (although it does give me a very understandable error message that it is MY program, which it is not sure about).

Solution: Turn off the virus check in the folder you are programming at (i.e. the folder with the solution of the project). I don't know AVG personally, but you should be able to set some sort of exception which are not included in the scan process.

Note: I do not take any responsibility if it is really a virus of some sort.